# Allow crawling of root and images folder in robots.txt without Disallow

Tags: robots.txt

I have small website with some pages in the root folder, some folders (js, css, images) and sitemap.

```
/index.php
/whoweare.php
/contacts.php
/sitemap.xml
/images/
/css/
/js/
```

I want Google to crawl only pages ( index.php, whoweare.php, contacts.php, sitemap.xml ), images folder and the sitemap.

This is my robots.txt, I'm not sure is correct:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /$
Allow: /images/
Allow: /sitemap.xml
```

Should I remove `Allow: /$` in this case would Google crawl php pages in root folder (I don't have any `Disallow` rule)?

Comment: For sitemap use this:    `Sitemap: http://www.yoursite.com/sitemap.xml`

Comment: It’s not clear which URLs you want to allow/disallow.

Comment: I update my question